# Close hidden batch file with a trigger

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, terminate

My current set up is I have a VBS file opening a batch file hidden in the background. This batch file can do some damage if anything is out of place so as a precaution I want to add a kill switch on say mouse click.

```
`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Auto.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing`
```

This is my VBS file so how could I add if click then terminate Auto.bat? I could also put it into the batch file but I'm scared it would get through to much code before it reaches the terminate line. I just need a click to terminate it otherwise, like I said earlier, it causes some damage!

Thanks in advance!

Here is the auto.bat file

```
 rem @echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for %%x in (*.pdf) do (
    set "_pdfname=%%x"
    call :doAllWork
)
goto :eof

:doAllWork
ECHO start
start %_pdfname%
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start select.vbs
start copy.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"
echo %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%
type NUL > TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
start TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
ECHO close PDF
start close.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start window.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start paste.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start save.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start close.vbs
start enter.vbs
rem                    v                 remove this backslash?
move /-y "%_pdfname%" "OldTimesheets\"
rem                    ^                 remove this backslash?
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
ECHO exit loop
if exist *.pdf (
    goto :eof
) else (
    goto :end
)


:end

cscript MessageBox.vbs "This will be shown in a popup."
```

Comment: Does the script open a console window?  Close that window to abort.  Otherwise as you suspect shutdown logic would need to go inside the .vbs.

Comment: no window opens so theres nothing to close but I ended up not needing it closed just changed the timeouts so everything would happen in order!

Comment: Hard to imagine a way your `Auto.bat` script _can do some damage if anything is out of place_. Write it safer! It's the best precaution, imho...

Comment: What kind of damage can your batch do ? can you at least post its code ?

Comment: @Hackoo It can re-write files if they're open and shuts down the computer regardless of files open.

Comment: @EduardAnghelescu As i can see in your batch, you have many vbs files to call and i guess that you use somes sendkeys into it ? so i wonder what close.vbs,window.vbs,paste.vbs,save.vbs,enter.vbs can achieve?

Comment: Alt f4 enter on desktop shuts down everything regardless if saved or not and there was no stopping it. @Hackoo Thanks for the help!